# Why Nest.js claims to be "progressive"?

Tags: javascript, nestjs

Just on the first page of Nest, they proudly claim :

> A **progressive** Node.js framework for building efficient, reliable and scalable server-side applications.

The only word I can't grasp is **progressive** and what that can means in the programming world.

Can anyone explain the concept to me?

Comment: It just means "modern". Which in layman's terms simply means "fancier than the competition". I don't think it is important enough to be an answer so I'm just leaving it as a comment. PWA or progressive-web-apps in your tag actually means something completely different. It means a web page that is a normal web page but can progressively (in stages) turn off online features and work completely offline if the page cannot connect to the server - it also allows PWA pages to be installed as icons on IOS and Android so the webpage behaves like an app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to a Dictionary on the web progressive means **happening or developing gradually or in stages**.

What I infer from their website about them is "NestJs Takes advantage of latest JavaScript features, bringing design patterns and mature solutions to Node.js world."

and indeed they are doing so by making it more extensible and versatile.

Well, this has nothing to do with PWA(Progressive Web App) Hope this answers your question.