# What is Progressive framework?

Tags: angular, vue.js, nestjs

I have gone through many online forums but still do not find any proper definition for what mean by Progressive framework.
Why NestJs, VueJs claim to be Progressive Framrwork?
Why Angular is not Progressive framework?

For NestJs, documentation (https://nestjs.com/) says "It Takes advantage of latest JavaScript features, bringing design patterns and mature solutions to Node.js world." Thats why it is Progressive. I am not able to digest this. How this one makes NestJs Progressive Framework?

Comment: "progressive" is not an established term in this context, also not related to PWA. You're asking about marketing buzzword. The meanings in slogans of Vue and Nest are not related.

Comment: Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67205590/why-nest-js-claims-to-be-progressive

Comment: @SurajRao: By that, every framework is gradually developing. That's for sure not the appropriate definition.